# Cache is building up with each load

Tags: google-analytics, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, browser-cache, cachestorage

I am working on [my portfolio website](https://mrjithin.netlify.app/). It is a PWA and there is a service worker. I am caching the index page and all the required assets of the index page using the service worker. But when I actually test it the cache size is building up with each load. After some experiments I found out that the problem is with the Google analytics script though I am not sure. But I cannot find a way to fix it. I had copied directly the code from Google analytics. Then as it didn't work, I tried to set the `crossorigin="anonymous"`. Then also it isn't working.

[Source code](https://github.com/mrjithin/my-portfolio/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your service worker's `fetch` handler unconditionally applies a caching strategy to all requests, regardless of what server is invovled.

If you want to avoid applying that strategy to requests made to third-party servers, like Google Analytics, you can exit the `fetch` handler early, before you call `event.respondWith()`. If you do that, then the normal network behavior will still apply, and you won't get any of the caching.

Assuming all of the assets that you want to cache are served from the same-origin server, you can do this with:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (url.origin !== location.origin) {
    return;
  }

  // event.respondWith() and the caching logic goes here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue. I went through some of your answers and I came to know that you wrote on of workbox's guide. Are you a Google employee?

Comment: Yes, I'm a member of Google's Web DevRel team, and a maintainer of Workbox.